# Creating a new table in sqlite database

Tags: qt, sqlite

Is this a legit way to create a new table in existing database, binding the name of the table?

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
string dbName = login;
dbName.append(".db");
if(!db.open())
{
    qDebug() << db.lastError();
    qFatal("Failed to connect");
}
qDebug("Connected");

QSqlQuery query(db);
query.prepare("CREATE TABLE :table (:value text NOT NULL);");
tableName.append("Top");
query.bindValue(":table" , QString::fromStdString(tableName));
query.bindValue(":value" , QString::fromStdString(criterion));
query.exec();
qDebug() << db.lastError();
```

I am not getting any errors, though the table is not being created. I would  really appreciate your help.

Comment: This is not allowed; the `prepare` should fail.

Comment: Do you mean that I can't bind table name this way?